# Difference between add-certificates, add-trusted-cert and import when using security CLI

Tags: macos, security, certificate

I've read the MAN page for the `security` command but there seems to be three ways to get certificate data into the machine.

`add-certificates`

Add certificates contained in the specified files to the default keychain.

`add-trusted-cert`

Add certificate (in DER or PEM format) from certFile to per-user or local Admin Trust Settings.

`import`

Import one or more items from inputfile into a keychain.

What's the difference? Or why would I choose one over the others?